# NodeJS aes-256-cfb decryption only works on first 16 bytes

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

The code below (a mocha test) produces:

```
  1) crypto should work:
     AssertionError: "a secret message which has more than sixteen bytes" 
== "a secret message�\u001d\r�\u001dͫ\u0000 ~��x\u000f�\u001bZ\u001bp?\u0014\u0010\u0011b��\u0003kJ\u001dcV8\t"
```

It's evident that the first sixteen bytes of the message are decrypted successfully, but that there is an error with subsequent data.

- What am I doing wrong?
- Why must I use 16 bytes (128 bits) of IV for AES256?  (I tried to use 32 bytes, but that caused an error.)

(Use of 'aes-256-cfb' is a requirement, the issues goes away if I choose aes-256-ctr.)

code/testcase:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var crypto = require('crypto');

describe('crypto', function() {
  it('should work', function () {
    var message = new Buffer('a secret message which has more than sixteen bytes');
    var key = new Buffer('fedcba9876543210fedcba9876543210fedcba9876543210fedcba9876543210', 'hex');
    var iv = new Buffer('0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef', 'hex');      

    var encrypted = encrypt(message, key, iv);
    assert.equal(message.length, encrypted.length);

    assert.equal(message.length, encrypted.length);
    assert.equal('05c2aad7bac42ed084739340d47cec9f03d8e94ac7b1e11a56a6654f76ad2c8076bca162303e39b44d043732e98fdd28c52d', encrypted.toString('hex'));

    var decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key, iv);

    assert.equal('a secret message which has more than sixteen bytes', decrypted.toString('utf8'));
  });
});

function encrypt(data, key, iv) {
  var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cfb', key, iv);
  var encrypted = cipher.update(data);
  var encfinal = cipher.final();

  return Buffer.concat([encrypted, encfinal]);
}

var decrypt = encrypt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `aes-256-cfb`, unlike `aes-256-ctr` is not symmetric.

The fix was to use `crypto.createDecipheriv` for deciphering.